# How break method execution in the TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have easy problem. I have method `setProductCart` and I have `for` loop and in for I have `if` condition and when I execute the condition I want to back out from method. I using `return` for that, but I am not sure that is correct.

```
setProductCart(product: ProductModel) {

        for (let i = 0; i < this.productCart.length; i++) {
            if (product.name == this.productCart[i].name) {

                this.productCart[i].price += product.price;
                this.productCart[i].numberOfProduct += 1;
                return;


            }
        }
        this.productCart.push(product);
        this.shopCartChanged.next(this.productCart);

    }
```

Does anyone know bather solution for this?

Comment: Yes, but I want after execution method to get out of method, I do not want to `execute this.productCart.push(product);
        this.shopCartChanged.next(this.productCart);`

Comment: To finish the execution of the method you can do that. You can also make a `break` within your loop to finish the loop an continue the method if needed.

Comment: You can also rewrite you code and use a map using your prod.name as key. So you dont have to loop over.

Comment: @J.Knabenschuh he should use a while loop with array.length and boolean condition, but regarding the code he posted, he should rewrite.

Comment: Yeah of courese, he could also do that. But what is the advantage? He can also extend the for loop condition with its condition, there are a view solutions. I thought it is also interesting to know that there is a special keyword for breaking loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the object in your array with built-in method [find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find).

```
setProductCard(product: ProductModel) {
  const prod = this.productCart.find((p) => p.name === product.name)
  if (prod) {
    prod.price += product.price;
    prod.numberOfProduct += 1;
  } else {
    this.productCart.push(product);
  }
  this.shopCartChanged.next(this.productCart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a map like structure like object instead of array, maybe it is useful in your case.

```
setProductCart(product: ProductModel) {
    let product = this.productCart[product.name];
    if(product) {
        product.price += product.price;
        product.numberOfProduct += 1;
    }
    else {
        this.productCart[product.name] = product;
        this.shopCartChanged.next(this.productCart);
    }
}
```

Comment: productCart is an array, you can only access items inside with an index, this will throw an error.

Comment: I know, this is an alternative solution not using an array as you see in my comment.

Comment: You talked about a Map, so if productCart is a Map object you should use `productCart.get(product.name)` to access it. Please clarify what is productCart in your solution